# Dynamic html pricing page language

Tags: jquery, html

What web langauges are used to make these dynamic pricing pages?

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

http://www.heroku.com/pricing

I know it probably involves jQuery for the sliders. The main thing I'm interested in finding out is the live-updating price works. I've seen something similar in a Rails app, but I want to keep out of a full-fledged app. I would like the data to by submitted through an HTML form.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Windows Azure is likely ASP.NET and jQuery since its a Microsoft product. You can use any combination of client and server languages to make a web app. Certain languages have better tools than others for certain tasks. Without any detail as to what you want to accomplish, its hard to answer.

Comment: I believe you're looking for javascript, jquery is a library that simplifies a lot of common redundant javascript tasks. And makes DOM manipulation easier. Not necessarily required for the pricing to update, (just don't take that value and send it to your server, recalculate it on the server) or for consistency use ajax to get the price from your server/backend code and return that to make sure the price is consistent.

Comment: Microsoft link is built on ASP.net by the looks of things.  The dynamic pricing is going to use a combination of things.  You're looking at server-side scripting to pull rates and information from a database and javascript/ajax to present the data to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Heroku's pricing page, the live-updating price field is modified in a JavaScript function attached to the movement of the sliders. So when the slider is moved, a function is executed, and this function is responsible for determining the correct price based on the current position of the sliders, then updating the listed price.

This page probably doesn't use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) for this since it can all be done client-side, but if you wanted to update a price while communicating with a server, Ajax is your friend. It allows you to submit information to a server, receive a response, and do something with that response *without* reloading the page. This is possible because JavaScript can do all this within the context of the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Check-out the documentation on the jQuery website regarding AJAX: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

In-fact, if you want to get into dynamic user interfaces for the web I suggest perusing the documentation of jQuery for a while to discover all the cool functions and methods it has.

But note that jQuery is a JavaScript framework and not a language of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jquery slider which is most likely used on both of the sites in one form or another.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range

Answer (score 0):

You can use any scripting language to achieve this. You can get a free XML feed of currency conversion rates updated daily (see: http://rss.timegenie.com/foreign_exchange_rates_forex). All you need to do is parse the XML file and create a custom method to search the values and convert from one currency to another. It is advisable to save the daily updated values into your own database and query that rather than spamming the XML source server.